# Install.xml file doesn't update the php file when installing it as an extension in opencart 3

Tags: php, xml, opencart-3, ocmod

I am working on an opencart project. There is a new module call discounts in the project implemented by another developer. I have copied the related files and related methods in to  a new project and it worked well. I have created a discount.ocmod.zip file with the new files related to the discount module and I have created the install.xml file to update a default php file(I'm updating the **product.php**), but after I install the extension, the files get copied to the correct locations, but **product.php doesn't get updated with my new functions.**  What am I doing wrong here?

This is the modification log.

[image]

This is my xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<modification>

<generator>Created with OpenIX - https://openix.io/en/tool/opencart/ocmod</generator>

<name>installment plan</name>

<version>0.1</version>

<code>20778</code>

<author>Thilina</author>

<link>www.test.com</link>


-<file path="admin/controller/catalog/product.php">


-<operation>


-<search>

-<![CDATA[// Image]]>
</search>


-<add position="before">

-<![CDATA[//Credit Cards
  if (isset($this->request->post['credit_cards'])) {
   $credit_cards = $this->request->post['credit_cards'];
  } elseif (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
   $credit_cards = $this->model_catalog_product->getCreditCards();
  } else {
   $data['credit_cards'] = array();
  }

  $data['credit_cards'] = array();

  foreach ($credit_cards as $credit_card) {
   $data['credit_cards'][] = array(
     'credit_card_id' => $credit_card['credit_card_id'],
     'credit_card_name'=> $credit_card['credit_card_name']);
  }

  //Installment Plan Product Ids
  if(!isset($this->request->get['product_id'])){
   $data['installment_plans'] = array();
  }else{
   $data['installment_plans'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getInstallmentPlansOfProduct($this->request->get['product_id']);
  }
]]>
</add>

</operation>

</file>

</modification>
```

Comment: Why do you have the "-" at the beginning of each line?

Comment: i have generated this xml from this website  https://openix.io/en/tool/opencart/ocmod

Comment: Given you comment, on my since deleted answer. What does the OCMOD log say? Please remove those incorrect "-"'s from the question so that it's easier for someone else to debug, since it's not actually in the xml file as you say.

Comment: Can you have a look and see if a file exists in this path: `/system/storage/modification/admin/controller/catalog/product.php` if so, download it and see if the modification has been applied

Comment: @Daniel yes it's there and it is updated.at first i was checking on admin/controller/catalog/product.php. now only i got know how it works. Thanks.